# How to use Reflection to attach event handler

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, reflection

I need to update the Enabled state of my Ribbon buttons based on my ViewModel's commands. Since VSTO Ribbons do not (yet?) support good old command binding, I'm trying to achieve this by listening to `CanExecuteChanged` event of all `RelayCommand` properties of my ViewModel. Instead of attaching every property separately, I thought I'd use Reflection and get all properties of `RelayCommand` type and attach my handler in a loop.

I can get all properties using following simple code:

```
var props = VM.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
  if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(RelayCommand))
     ????.CanExecuteChanged += MyHandler;
}
```

What do I need to write in place of `????`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have found a property of type `RelayCommand`, to add yourself as a handler to its `CanExecuteChanged` event, you need to:

1. Retrieve the property value.
2. Cast the property value to `RelayCommand`
3. Subscribe to the event.

E.g.

```
if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(RelayCommand))
{
    RelayCommand command = (RelayCommand)prop.GetValue(VM);

    command.CanExecuteChanged += MyHandler;
}
```

Finally note that the `CanExecuteChanged` event is actually declared in the `ICommand` interface, which typical implementations of `RelayCommand` (which is not a standard .NET type, but rather a commonly used WPF idiom). So you might prefer something like this instead:

```
if (typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
{
    ICommand command = (ICommand)prop.GetValue(VM);

    command.CanExecuteChanged += MyHandler;
}
```

Comment: `prop.GetValue(VM)`: This, my friend, was the missing piece. Thanks a bunch.